# Get the Data from one sheet to another Sheet by applying multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to this VBA Coding. Someone can help me with this please.
I have some data in Sheet1 and I would like to copy the data to Sheet2 with the following conditions.
If "K"="yes" then L,M,N,O,P should be in next row. In the same way if "Q"="Yes" then R,S,T,U,V should be in the next row.  Here is the Sample Data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biQcy.png)

Output expected: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Rbq.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a 

question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below might do what you are asking:

```
Sub MyMacro()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    emptyrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 4).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 6).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 7).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 8).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 9).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 10).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value
Check = UCase(Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).Value)
    If Check = "YES" Then
        emptyrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 4).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 6).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 12).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 7).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 13).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 8).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 14).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 9).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 15).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 10).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 16).Value
    End If
Check = UCase(Sheet1.Cells(i, 17).Value)
    If Check = "YES" Then
        emptyrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 4).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 6).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 18).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 7).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 19).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 8).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 20).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 9).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 21).Value
        Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 10).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 22).Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The output on Sheet2 would be like below:

```
Team    Team    Team    Member      Team Member
Jame    Rich    11      One of My   Great Teacher
Tar     Scott   98      Rockstar    Rockstar
Ash     Mit     94      good team   Great!
Kate    Wilde   1       One of my   One of my
```

Comment: Than you!!! Your code helped me a lot and I have one more question. I want A to J data in 1st row and if "K"="Yes" then A,B,C,D,E,L,M,N,O,P in the 2nd row and If "Q"="Yes" then A,B,C,D,E,R,S,T,U,V in the 3rd Row.  Is there any way to get the data in this way?

Comment: @ram please have a look at the updated code, I think this will do what you want it to do... :)

Comment: Hi!!! when I am using the updated code I am getting error as "Run-time error '424':  Object Required".... Error is Showing in "LastRow = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row" this line can you please help me with this. Thank you in advance

Comment: Where it says "LastRow = Sheet" you need to have the sheet number in there, if the main sheet is Sheet1, then it should read as "LastRow =Sheet1.cells(Sheet1.rows.count, "A").end(xlUp).Row

Comment: One last question is there any way we can use the looping condition to the last column? Like In my Excel Sheet last data entered column is "FB" do I need to write the code up to "Check = UCase(Sheet1.Cells(i, 202).Value)" and the condition is for "11"= "YES" then print the value then next again "(11+6=17)"="yes" print the values

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, if what you want to do is include the checks for the value "Yes" on the column FB, the code should read "Check = UCase(Sheet1.cells(i, 157).value